# SQL Server : deduct adjacent columns group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, view

The logic behind is, I am developing a report using SSRS. The problem I am facing is, on one table I have an Amount field (in this case A column) and on the other table i have Amount to be deducted (In this case B column).

When I show this records on a report (ssrs) it is showing as the following (first table), but the output they are looking for is the second one.

How it works: the A column is the result of A-B (6.000 - 2.000) except for the first one,  and this result (6.000 - 2.000 = 4.000) will be set on A.

What I have now:

```
id  A       B       
-----------------
1   6.000   2.000   
2   6.000   1.000   
3   6.000   2.000   
4   6.000   1.000
```

Expected output

```
id  A       B       C
-------------------------
1   6.000   2.000   4.000 
2   4.000   1.000   3.000
3   3.000   2.000   1.000
4   1.000   1.000   0.000
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  And, your output makes no sense.  What happened to the decimal places?  Please edit your question and explain the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I've added ROW_NUMBER in case there would be some gaps between IDs. If no - just ignore it and use your id field in this scenario.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    id INT
    , A FLOAT
    , B FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO @data
    (id, A, B)
VALUES
      (1, 6.000, 2.000)
    , (2, 6.000, 1.000)
    , (3, 6.000, 2.000)
    , (4, 6.000, 1.000)
    , (6, 5.000, 1.000);

;WITH ordered (rn, id, A, B)
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn, id, A, B
    FROM @data
),
cte
AS (
    SELECT rn, id, A, B, A-B AS C
    FROM ordered
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.rn, T.id, C.C, T.B, C.C - T.B
    FROM ordered AS T
    INNER JOIN cte AS C
        ON c.rn + 1 = T.rn
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

**Additional example using analytic functions:**

```
;WITH ordered (previous_id, id, A, B)
AS (
    SELECT LAG(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) , id, A, B
    FROM @data
),
cte
AS (
    SELECT previous_id, id, A, B, A-B AS C
    FROM ordered
    WHERE previous_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.previous_id, T.id, C.C, T.B, C.C - T.B
    FROM ordered AS T
    INNER JOIN cte AS C
        ON c.id = T.previous_id
)
SELECT id, A, B, C
FROM cte
```

**Output:**

```
rn  id  A   B   C
------------------
1   1   6   2   4
2   2   4   1   3
3   3   3   2   1
4   4   1   1   0
5   6   0   1   -1
```

Comment: Thank you. let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: I've also added additional solution using LAG function, maybe you will like it more.